# How to align with braces?

Tags: equations

Can anyone help me to write this?

[image]

Latex doesn't allow me to use BRACES and ALIGN.

```
\begin{equation}\label{peqdef}
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
&\textrm{div}\textbf{T}=0, && \textbf{T}=2G\textbf{E}+\lambda \textrm{tr}\textbf{E}-p\textbf{I}\\
&\textrm{div}\dot{\textbf{u}}=-\textrm{div} \textbf{j} \\
&\textrm{det}\textbf{F}=1+\textrm{tr} (\nabla \textbf{u})= 1+\upsilon c
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `align` inside an equation. Use `aligned` instead (or `alignedat`). And using `cases` just to get the brace is abusing a tool for a task it was not designed for.

Here is a better version. I fixed some other issues at the same time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{peqdef}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \Div\mathbf{T}&=0,
      & \mathbf{T}&=2G\mathbf{E}+\lambda \tr\mathbf{E}-p\mathbf{I}\\
      \Div\dot{\mathbf{u}}&=-\Div \mathbf{j} \\
      \det\mathbf{F}&=1+\tr (\nabla \mathbf{u})= 1+\upsilon c
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `\left\{` … `\right.`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for solving this problem. I had no clue. Thank you

Comment: @Ingrid please accept the answer since it solves your problem